# Call order with frames involved

Tags: javascript, iframe, scope

I have a html page with an embedded iframe. Is it possible to reference a global variable at window.top without the prefix (window.top or similar), or does one always have to use the full path to access a variable from an embedded frame. In a quick test in Google Chrome I could not access a variable at the window.top level without the prefix, but I have a sneaking suspicion that this has been possible to do earlier/in other browsers/in some situations. My question is: if there is no variable with sought name in the iframe's local scope (the iframe's contentWindow), will the browser (some browsers?) automatically look at the next higher level (the parent level window which can belong to another frame/iframe or window.top) and return that value/object? And: if there are duplicate variable names at the local embedded iframe level and a parent level, will the local level always win out or can there be situations where the the window.top version gains precedence?

Answer (score 0):

> if there is no variable with sought name in the iframe's local scope (the iframe's contentWindow), will the browser (some browsers?) automatically look at the next higher level (the parent level window which can belong to another frame/iframe or window.top) and return that value/object?

No.